# How to prevent delete of a div in tinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to prevent deletion of the divs .panel-heading and .panel-body when the user press delete or backspace keys on the editor. This is the div that appears on the editor:

```
<div class="panel panel-default tab">
    <div class="panel-heading "><h3 class="panel-title">test title</h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body "><p>test body</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

On the setup function of the editor try this:

```
          ed.on("keydown",function(e) {
                //prevent empty panels
                if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) { //backspace and delete keycodes
                    try {
                        var elem = ed.selection.getNode().parentNode; //current caret node
                        if (elem.classList.contains("panel-body") || elem.classList.contains("panel-heading")) {
                            if (elem.textContent.length == 0) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (e) {}
                }
            });
```